# ruby on rails multiple object in find condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I add multiple objects in a find condition? 
I created a table for comments but I want to display comments posted by a user and
his or her friends. 
I got the find method to return a list of comments by a user's friends but I cannot get the 
'find' method to include the user as well.

For example:

```
User = profile.find(1)
Comment.find(:all, :conditions => {:profile_id => user.friends})
```

This works great but I also need to have the current user in the list of comments as well.
I tried this with no luck:

```
Comment.find(:all, :conditions => {:profile_id => [user, user.friends]})
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Comment.find_all_by_profile_id([user.friends, user].flatten)
```

Same as:

```
Comment.all(:conditions => {:profile_id => [user.friends, user].flatten})
```

Comment: @brian: If you accept an answer, please also give it an up vote.